# How do I enable clicking default POI markers in mapkit js

Tags: mapkit, apple-maps, mapkit-js

I am using mapkit js.
var map = new mapkit.Map('mymap',
{
center: center,
cameraDistance: 300,
showsZoomControl: true,
showsPointsOfInterest: true,
});

And after map initialized it come with some default POIs with icons like Apple map result.
I want to get the POI info when clicking POI icons. For example, POI name, coordinates, address, ..., etc.

How should I do that? I tried addEventListener, but with no luck. What object will be returned when clicking POI icons?

Comment: Does something happen when you click on the POI? Because when I do, nothing happens so I am thinking there might be no functionality to interact with the POIs